# Does the complexity of a closure affect the performance cost of creating it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, dom

Suppose I have the following React hook:

```js
export const useSomeState = (someProps: {}) => {
  return React.useState(() => {
    // Some really complex function with lots of code
  })
}
```

Because we are using the function handler to React.useState, the state should only be initted once.. thats fine...

If this hook is used as part of a larger component that is re-rendered frequently does this hurt performance? Or do I need to use React.useCallback or something?

What is the performance cost of JS creating and re-creating a closure (on each re-render) that it will never run?

And does the complexity of the closure (number of variables captured and put on the heap) affect the performance cost?

Comment: have you considered using useMemo hook?

Comment: Why using function in a state if you dont intend to change this state?

Comment: @adirabargil because the function version of useState() is only executed once when the component is mounted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first concern with re-creating multiple closures isn't the speed cost, but the memory cost.  There's little difference between creating a closure over 1 vs 10 variables, but that does require a small heap allocation. Lots of small heap allocations can fragment memory, requiring more garbage-collection runs, which DO impact performance, at odd and unpredictable times.

If your closure is getting re-created on every animation frame, then yeah, you should probably improve the code.  If it's only on re-render of some page within Main Content, you're probably fine.